# Good way to break monotony on "never-ending" apps

Tags: usability, interaction-design

As a good example/case-study of this, let us consider running type of video games (e.g. temple run) or swipe left/right type of dating apps, or image browsing apps, etc.

In general, these apps "just keep going". In Temple Run, you just keep running (at ever increasing pace) until you crash. Tinder/OkCupid just lets you continually swipe left/right (as far as I know). Similarly most image browsing apps seem like a bottomless page where you can just keep scrolling down to find more content.

The same applies to older games like monopoly/risk.

I feel this can get boring. Is there a good way to break the monotony of this sort of experience and somehow make it more interesting?

Or, is there actually some sort of charm to this never ending aspect that draws people in?

PS - this is my first question on this SE, so please feel free to help fix the question/tags if needed.

Comment: This is opinion based. What you and millions find monotonous and boring, other millions find cool. That's why there exist millions of games. I suggest to close this topic.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the point of the question was about how to break the monotony for those that do find it so.. ways of breaking the monotony is actually a very valid topic - especially in areas of game design, etc (which is why there are varied weapons, different enemies, arenas, background music scores, etc.). So I was hoping someone the right experience could chip in.

Answer (score 1):

1. Inverse it: Not the player should control the hero, but computer. And the player should control the obstacles.
2. Use multiplayer mode. Then the game will be slightly different each time, because people are different. And player will be focused not only on the game elements, but also on another players.
3. Make the maximal duration short. Then the game will not become boring.
4. Limit the maximal number of plays per hour or per day. Then the game will not become boring.
5. Limit resources available to the player. For instance, for apps like Tinder limit the number of profiles or swipes to 10 or to 100 per day.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The points are indeed valuable but the question wasn't specific to games but was on more generic lines.

Comment: @Yogesch that's exactly why you won't find an answer here. Your question is too broad and vague albeit interesting.